# Drivers no disponibles en QT y PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, qt-creator

Estoy intentando realizar una conexión mediante QT a una base de datos PostgreSQL. El código que estaba utilizando es el siguiente:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("19x.xxx.xx.xx");
    db.setDatabaseName("baseDatos");
    db.setPort(5432);
    db.setUserName("usuario");
    db.setPassword("contra");

    bool ok = db.open();

    if(ok) qDebug() << "Conectado";
    else "No se pudo conectar";


    return a.exec();
}
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el programa se obtiene lo siguiente:

QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers:

Estoy usando PostgreSQL 10 y QT 5.8. ¿Cómo podría incluir esos drivers? Gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es tu OS y compilador?

Comment: El SO es Windows 8 y el compilador Visual Studio C++ 2015

Comment: Revisa el siguiente enlace: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql